# Attempt to use calc() in CSS does not work

Tags: css

Here's a simplified version of my CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: calc(1.5 * (100vw - 50) + 2);
}
```

The calculation for line-height doesn't work. It has something to do with the `100vw`, but I'm not sure what. My understanding is that `100vw` should be converted into 100% of the pixels of the current viewport (e.g. 414 ... so the math should be: `1.5 * (414 - 50) + 2`).

If the `vw` unit is removed, then the calculation works (i.e. `1.5 * (100 - 50) + 2`). What's going on here? Why isn't `100vw` working?

Here's my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv68au4o/1/

Comment: [mcve] here please, not on a third party site

Comment: Doesn't my code sample already do that?

Comment: `100vw - 50` - fifty *what*? If you tell the browser what you're working with (`px`, `vw`, `vh`, `%`...) I imagine it will work better.

Comment: You're required to post a [mcve] here, not on a third party site. Sort of surprised with your rep that you're not aware of that. Third party sites rot, get blocked, and can disappear for a variety of reasons, leaving your question useless for future visitors.

Comment: what is what is `2` unit ? `px ?`

Comment: If you add or subtract something in a calculation, your need to add the correct unit.

Comment: *My understanding is that 100vw should be converted into 100% of the pixels of the current viewport* --> not at all, you are expecting too much from calc(). What you are doing is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line-height: calc(1.5 * (100vw - 50px));

try this and reduce the px according to your requirement.